# Is it possible for a godzilla-like creature to be created using genetic modifications?

Tags: genetic-engineering

This 'Godzilla' should be THE godzilla featured in the films Godzilla, and Godzilla, King of The Monsters. Of course, the main issue will be the atomic breath. Is it physically possible, with mastery of genetic modification, to be able to create such a creature? Note-the 'atomic breath' doesnt have to be radioactive, it just has to deal a obscene amount of damage to anything in it's path.

Comment: Could you expand on that question?  By, like, a lot?

Comment: Many of the gene editing tools are used to treat some diseases in human and occasionally upsize our food in record time, but to produce GMO marine iguana we probably still need to study a gazillion of genes and their corresponding traits. So more manpower needed urgently anyone?

Comment: Consider making this one of the [Anatomically Correct](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2797/40609) questions. I'm actually a bit surprised Godzilla hasn't been done before. HOWEVER, please follow the AC rules to the letter. You can't just point to a movie and you can't ask a lazy question (as written at the time of my comment, this is a lazy question) - you need to bring all the description you can into the question. Remember, one specific question, one best answer.

Comment: Related: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/127407

Comment: VTC as duplicate.  There are lots of "how big can a biological monster be?" questions on the site.  The answer to this question, without magic, is "no".

Comment: @jdunlop The question suggests the main problem is Godzilla's atomic breath or its near equivalent, and how to achieve it. the answer may still be "no", but that hasn't been duplicated in other questions. It helps if you read questions carefully & thoughtfully.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The size, for a start, makes it completely impossible for a bipedal creature. A whale that size might conceivably work, but supporting its own weight as Godzilla does would be impossible.

The atomic breath would be impossible because 'atomic breath' is not a thing.  Exhaling radioactive gas would be another matter but would not give the effect you are after.